# Calculate Counts and Add Table to Razor Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, html-table, count, razor-pages

I have a Referrals database table. Here is part of the model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Referrals.Model
{
    public class Referral
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Referral No (###.#-YYYY)")]
        public string RefNoComplete { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date Received")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateReceived { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Meeting Month")]
        public string? BoardMtgMonth { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Meeting Year")]
        public string? BoardMtgYear { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Application Type")]
        public string? ApplicationType { get; set; }
```

I need to get counts for each application type for each 'BoardMtgYear'.

The format I would like it to return is (preferably right justified):

| ApplicationType | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arch Review | 3 | 15 | 12 |
| Area Variance | 65 | 64 | 63 |
| Comp Plan | 14 | 24 | 27 |
| Local Law | 5 | 2 | 6 |
| Major Subdiv | 15 | 22 | 13 |
| Totals | 106 | 127 | 121 |

I need to get this onto my razor page and need to have a way to input the year parameters. So, the user would enter 2019, 2020, 2021 (or whatever years they need - it just needs to compare 3 years)

Here is what I have on my view. I know I have butchered the syntax, but that is what I need help with.

It would also be great to have a total of each year column at the bottom of the table, but I don't even know where to start with html for that!

```
@page
@model Referrals.Pages.Reports.AppTypeByYear.IndexModel

<partial name="_Notification" />

<div id="" class="container p-3">


    <br /><br />

    <form asp-page="./Index" method="post">
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <p>
                Input First Year: <input type="text" name="firstyear" value="" />, Second Year: <input type="text" name="secondyear" value="" /> and Last Year: <input type="text" name="thirdyear" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary mx-2" />
                <a asp-page="./Index" class="btn btn-link mx-2">Return to Full List</a>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="AppTypeTable"class="row pt-4">
            <div class="col-25">
                <h2 class="text-primary" align="center">Planning Board</h2>
                <h3 class="text-primary" align="center">Referral Applications By Type By Year</h3>
            </div>

            <table id="ReferralTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Referral Type
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            First Year
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Middle Year
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Last Year
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    @foreach (var obj in Model.Referral)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td width="60%">@obj.ApplicationType</td>
                            <td width="20%">count(@obj.BoardMtgYear.Where <param name="firstyear" />)</td>
                            <td width="20%">count(@obj.BoardMtgYear.Where<param name="secondyear" />)</td>
                            <td width="20%">count(@obj.BoardMtgYear.Where<param name="thirdyear" />)</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks for any and all assistance. I am still a beginner at both C# and razor pages.

EDITED TO ADD: Revised .cs:

```
using Referrals.Data;
using Referrals.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Referrals.Pages.Reports.AppTypeByYear;

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public IEnumerable<Referral> Referral { get; set; }
    public List<Referral> BoardMtgYear1 { get; set; }
    public List<Referral> BoardMtgYear2 { get; set; }
    public List<Referral> BoardMtgYear3 { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
    public void OnPost(string firstyear, string secondyear, string thirdyear)
    {
        BoardMtgYear1 = Referral.Where(a => a.BoardMtgYear == firstyear).ToList();
        BoardMtgYear2 = Referral.Where(a => a.BoardMtgYear == secondyear).ToList();
        BoardMtgYear3 = Referral.Where(a => a.BoardMtgYear == thirdyear).ToList();
    }

}
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to enter the three year's values as search condition. Then you can get counts for each `Applicationtype` for each 'BoardMtgYear'. Also get count for each year in the last row.

A whole working demo you could follow:

Page

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<div id="" class="container p-3">   

    <br /><br />   
    <form asp-page="./Index" method="post">
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <p>
                Input First Year: <input type="text" name="firstyear" value="" />, Second Year: <input type="text" name="secondyear" value="" /> and Last Year: <input type="text" name="thirdyear" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary mx-2" />
                <a asp-page="./Index" class="btn btn-link mx-2">Return to Full List</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        @if (Model.Referral != null && Model.Referral.Count() != 0)
        {
            <div id="AppTypeTable" class="row pt-4">
                <div class="col-25">
                    <h2 class="text-primary" align="center">Planning Board</h2>
                    <h3 class="text-primary" align="center">Referral Applications By Type By Year</h3>
                </div>

                <table id="ReferralTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Referral Type
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                First Year
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Middle Year
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Last Year
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        @foreach (var obj in Model.Referral.Select(a=>a.ApplicationType).Distinct())
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td width="60%">@obj</td>
                                <td>@Model.BoardMtgYear1.Where(a=>a.ApplicationType==obj).Count()</td>
                                <td>@Model.BoardMtgYear2.Where(a=>a.ApplicationType==obj).Count()</td>
                                <td>@Model.BoardMtgYear3.Where(a=>a.ApplicationType==obj).Count()</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                        <tr>
                            <td width="60%">Total</td>
                            <td>@Model.BoardMtgYear1.Count()</td>
                            <td>@Model.BoardMtgYear2.Count()</td>
                            <td>@Model.BoardMtgYear3.Count()</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            
        }

    </form>
</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <style>
        tr{
            text-align:right;
        }
    </style>
}
```

PageModel

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public List<Referral> Referral { get; set; } 
    public List<Referral> BoardMtgYear1 { get; set; }
    public List<Referral> BoardMtgYear2 { get; set; }
    public List<Referral> BoardMtgYear3 { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        
    }
    public void OnPost(string firstyear,string secondyear,string thirdyear)
    {
        //hard-coded the data for easy testing....
        Referral  = new List<Referral>()
        {
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2019",ApplicationType="aa"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2019",ApplicationType="aa"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2019",ApplicationType="aa"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2019",ApplicationType="bb"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2019",ApplicationType="bb"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2019",ApplicationType="cc"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2019",ApplicationType="cc"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2019",ApplicationType="cc"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2020",ApplicationType="aa"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2020",ApplicationType="aa"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2020",ApplicationType="bb"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2020",ApplicationType="bb"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2020",ApplicationType="bb"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2020",ApplicationType="cc"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2021",ApplicationType="aa"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2021",ApplicationType="bb"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2021",ApplicationType="bb"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2021",ApplicationType="cc"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2021",ApplicationType="cc"},
            new Referral(){BoardMtgYear="2021",ApplicationType="cc"},
        };
        BoardMtgYear1 = Referral.Where(a => a.BoardMtgYear == firstyear).ToList();
        BoardMtgYear2 = Referral.Where(a => a.BoardMtgYear == secondyear).ToList(); 
        BoardMtgYear3 = Referral.Where(a => a.BoardMtgYear == thirdyear).ToList();         
    }       
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. It works for me with the static list, but then does NOT work if I remove the list. I have added an image of the error message as well as my revised .cs in the likely case that I have deleted something I shouldn't have!

Comment: Hi, your code never gets the value for `Referral`, of course it will receive the null exception. For easy testing, I just hard coded the list value in my answer. For yourself you can get it from database. e.g. `Referral=_db.Referral.ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks so much. That worked perfectly. I'm at that stage where I "almost know", but just lacking the syntax skills! One other thing I am wondering and not sure how to do is to pull the parameter values, so that on the view page, rather than "First Year", "Second Year" and "Last Year" the parameter values would be the headings - 2019 2020 2021. Is that very involved to do? Can you guide me? Thank you!!

Comment: Nevermind! Figured that one out on my own!

Comment: On last question - unless I figure it out. Is there a way to sort this by the Referral type column and make it ascending only? I don't need to search and I don't need to change the sort. Wondering if there is just a way to "hard code" the sort on the view page only without adding code to the .cs?

Comment: You need change the foreach loop:`@foreach (var obj in Model.Referral.OrderByDescending(a=>a.ApplicationType).Select(a=>a.ApplicationType).Distinct())`. Or using `.OrderBy(a=>a.ApplicationType).....`

Comment: Thanks so much. That works perfectly. I had tried sticking the OrderBy in that spot, but neglected to add the (a=>a.ApplicationType) as I thought the code could read the 2nd reference to it. ie, Model.Referral.OrderBy.Select(a => a.ApplicationType).Distinct()) My bad. Makes sense now. :)